# php numeric Variable Name

Tags: php, variables, auto-increment

I want to append some $variables automaticly and set their names numeric
I have a script look like this:

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while($i<=100){

$variable_[$i]=$i;
$i++;
#with "[$i]" I mean their name will be $variable_1 , $variable_2, $variable_3 ... 
#they will be automatic increased variables non manual!

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

You can set a variable variable by defining its name inside a variable, such as:

```
$name = 'variable_' . $i;
```

and then assign a value to it by doing:

```
$$name = $i;
```

Note that variable variables can easily be misused. Make sure you completely understand the repercussions of this feature on your code and the risk of having bugs, and ensure this is the only solution you have, i.e. you can't use an array (`$variables[$i] = $i;`) instead.

Comment: @gomi: I don't understand your comment, nor why are you putting two dollar symbols before `name`. I suppose the following quote from [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is relevant: *"if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second."*

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use Array with key=> value pair. You can build this array dynamically and then loop through it by using foreach.